# Any leads on using k6 for temporal workflows load testing ? Any references if we can achieve it

Tags: load-testing, k6, temporal-workflow

Can we use k6 to test temporal workflows load testing?
Is there any references which would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a new k6 Extension being developed: https://github.com/temporalio/xk6-temporal/